# ViewChildren duplicate element

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am struggling now for some hours to figure this out and i couldn't. For some reason the lenght of the `#grid` and `#label` templates are 1 element more and i don't know why the first element is duplicated. 
Here is how i get them :

```
@ViewChildren('grid') grids: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren('label') labels: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

And when i show their lenght , the result is 3 instead of 2-> this is the lenght of `availableServices`

```
console.log('grids len : ' + this.grids.length);
console.log('labels len : '  + this.labels.length);

<RadListView [items]="availableServices" class="radlist-group"
                        swipeActions="true" (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)"
                        (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)" backgroundColor="#26252A" style="height:100%">
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-service="item">
                    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" backgroundColor="#26252A">
                        <GridLayout class="item"
                                    [id]="service.name"
                                    #grid
                                    rows="*, *, 2*" columns="100, *, 10">
                            <StackLayout row="0" rowSpan="3" col="0" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" height="80" width="80" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" borderRadius="5">
                                <Label class="detailLabels" [text]="hi"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout row="0" col="1" rowSpan="2" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" height="24" width="40%" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" borderRadius="5">
                                <Label class="detailLabels" [text]="service.minutes + ' minutes'"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout row="2" col="1" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" height="40" width="100%" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" borderRadius="5">
                                <Label class="detailLabels" [text]="service.name"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                </ng-template>

                <GridLayout *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="*, auto">
                    <StackLayout id="delete-view" col="1"
                                 class="delete-view">
                        <Image #label src="res://check-mark" height="80" width="100" (tap)="add($event)"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>

            </RadListView>
```

Comment: `availableServices` is the data source but you are iterating through the children of your `grid`. So you GridLayoutr has three (3) children (StackLayouts) and for each of them there is a swipe template with a Label (again total of three Labels). So everything is  just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use ID or ViewChildren for elements inside ListView. Due to it's nature of reusing elements based on screen size, it may not always match the length of your data items.

Always play with data but not the element itself.